# worklight generated .apk only displaying static data not proper layout or components

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

my app is using dojo and it runs properly on worklight simulator, but when i run the apps .apk file on android device(handset) static html page displays i.e. index.html displays plain data not dojo component or any other components.
Can anybody help resolve this problem

Comment: Please be more descriptive... do you see any errors in LogCat? What is your Worklight version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is poorly written. You should consider editing it and adding more information to work with.

The following questions sound most related to it:

- [Worklight core-web-layer.js errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546952/worklight-core-web-layer-js-errors)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to resolve 404 errors for javascript map files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032574/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-resolve-404-errors-for-javascript-map-files)
- [Worklight 6.1 Android Applicaiton renders all views with no widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712376/worklight-6-1-andorid-applicaiton-renders-all-views-with-no-widgets)
- [Dojo Library loading error in Worklight project when trying to access from other Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438595/dojo-library-loading-error-in-worklight-project-when-trying-to-access-from-other)
- [Dojo-based application UI not working as expected in physical device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566543/worklight-application-ui-not-working-as-expected-in-real-device)
- [Error on real device . White screen and error:multiple define and script error on dojo.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104718/error-on-real-device-white-screen-and-errormultiple-define-and-script-error-o)
- [IBM Worklight with Dojo Toolkit | dojo/main.js 404 not found issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434503/ibm-worklight-with-dojo-toolkit-dojo-main-js-404-not-found-issue)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Hybrid Android Application not working in Emulator and Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480254/ibm-worklight-6-0-hybrid-android-application-not-working-in-emulator-and-devic)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - scriptError in dojo.js:21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603370/ibm-worklight-6-0-scripterror-in-dojo-js21)
- [IBM Worklight - Unable to load index.html in a Dojo app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964761/ibm-worklight-unable-to-load-index-html-in-a-dojo-app)
- [Deploying a Worklight app onto the Android Emulator is giving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947821/deploying-a-worklight-app-onto-the-android-emulator-is-giving-an-error)